# Proper way to use Firestore diff

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm Calling this function to retrieve users from firestore: 
Each time a user is modify I want to update the users array.

```
func fetchUsers( complete: @escaping ( _ success: Bool, _ users: [User], _ error: Error? )->()) {
    //self.users = []
    let circleId  = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "circleId") ?? ""
    DataService.call.REF_CIRCLES.document(circleId).collection("insiders").order(by: "position", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }


        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in

            if (diff.type == .added) {
                let data = diff.document.data()
                let id = diff.document.documentID
                let user = User(key: id, data: data)
                self.users.append(user)
                complete(true, self.users, nil)
            }

            if (diff.type == .modified) {
                // Update users array if user data is modified
                if !self.users.isEmpty {
                    self.users = []
                let data = diff.document.data()
                let id = diff.document.documentID
                let user = User(key: id, data: data)
                self.users.append(user)
                complete(true, self.users, nil)
                }
            }

            if (diff.type == .removed) {
                print("Removed user: \(diff.document.data())")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However my array always return 1 if there's only one user modified and my collectionview reload and then only show one user! How do I 
return all the users even if only one was modified? 
Thanks

**New Function:**

```
func fetchUsers( complete: @escaping ( _ success: Bool, _ users: [User], _ error: Error? )->()) {
    self.users = []
    let circleId  = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "circleId") ?? ""
    DataService.call.REF_CIRCLES.document(circleId).collection("insiders").order(by: "position", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

             snapshot.documents.forEach { diff in
                let data = diff.data()
                let id = diff.documentID
                let user = User(key: id, data: data)
                self.users.append(user)
                complete(true, self.users, nil)
         }
    }
}
```

Now I'm seeing a lot of duplicate users in my collectionview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over [`QuerySnapshot.documentChanges`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot#documentchanges), which only contains documents that changed since the last snapshot.

To get all documents in the query (instead of just the modified ones), loop over [`QuerySnapshot.documents`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/QuerySnapshot#documents) instead:

```
DataService.call.REF_CIRCLES.document(circleId).collection("insiders").order(by: "position", descending: false).addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }

    snapshot.documents.forEach { diff in
      ...
```

Comment: I did it but now my data is getting duplicated, Everytime a user is modify

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior. Every time there is a change to the `insiders , you get called with all new data. You'll either have to clear the `self.users` collection every time you get called, or you have to only listen once with `observeSingleEvent`, or listen for individual event types (i.e. `.childAdded`).